# Find the inverse function...

Tags: functions, logarithms

So, I have the function
$$f(x)=\frac{2^x-2^{-x}}{2}.$$
I tried finding the inverse function the usual way I do, but I guess I'm stuck with these degrees. So far, I've come to this form
$$y=\frac{2^{2x}-2^0}{2^{x+1}}.$$
When I used Wolfram Alpha Inverse Function Finder, it gave me this solution
$$f^{-1}(x)=\log\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)/\log(2).$$
I have no idea how it god those logs, please help me :D

Comment: Maybe try to get a different expression for $f$ by taking the second derivative and solving the resulting second order ODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{2^x - 2^{-x}}{2} = y \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad (2^x)^2 - 2y \cdot 2^x - 1 = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$f(x)=\frac{e^{x \log2}-e^{-x \log2}}{2}=\cosh (x \log2)=y, $$
so that $$x=\frac{1}{\log 2} \text{arccosh }y. $$